# Find matching values in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to iterate over a list of lists in python 2.7.5 and return those where the first value is found in a second list, something like this:

```
#python 2.7.5
list1 = ['aa', 'ab', 'bb', 'bc', 'cc']
list2 = [['aa', 1, 3, 7],['de', 2, 2, 1],['bc', 3, 4, 4]]

list3 = []
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        if x == y:
            list3.append(y)
```

So I would want list3 to contain `[['aa',1,3,7],['bc', 3, 4, 4]]` but instead I just get the whole of list2.

Comment: Huh? It won't give you the whole of `list2`, it'll give you an empty list. Please check the code again.

Comment: Is there a specific reason the second structure needs to be a list of lists instead of, say, a single dict?

Comment: In this case I think it would be helpful to tell us, what you want to achieve with your program/script (not only the presented piece of code). Because on a first glance I would guess that there exists better datastructures to solve your problem (like dicts)

Comment: This might be homework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try a more simple approach that is closer to what you want:

```
for e in list2:
    if e[0] in list1:
        list3.append(e)
```

You need `e[0]` since `list2` is a list of lists. You can also write this in a single line using the [filter() function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
list3 = filter(lambda e: e[0] in list1, list2)
```

or using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list3 = [e for e in list2 if e[0] in list1]
```

Answer (score 2):

There's just a bug in your code.  You need x == y[0] instead of x == y.  The latter is comparing a string to a list.

You can also use list comprehensions

```
>>> [x for x in list2 if x[0] in list1]
[['aa', 1, 3, 7],['bc', 3, 4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your issue is because you are attempting to compare a list of elements against a list of a list of elements.

If you step through the `for` loop, you'll see that on your first iteration you are comparing
`'aa'` against `['aa', 1, 3, 7]`, which is probably not what you would like to do.

If you're just comparing the first element, you will need to change your `for` loop to:

```
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        if x == y[0]:
            list3.append(y)
```